# Where to place web sites (vhosts) in Ubuntu?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

I'm setting up ubuntu w/ apache for some web development and I'm wondering where you place the web sites themselves (/home, /var)? I will host multiple domain using vhosts.

I know that there is no standard for this, but I'm wondering how experienced server admins reason when chosing between /home or /var wrt security, permissions, easy of use, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default locations are these:

The configuration files for the vhosts are under `/etc/apache2/sites-available`; create a new file here then run `a2ensite sitename` to enable the config.

The web site's content files themselves are under `/var/www`.

Comment: So /var/www is officially default for ubuntu?

Comment: Yup - you'll see that the default index.html page from the install is located there.